# Count occurunces of a value up to each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet like this

```
   Name     case_type    Count 
1  vijam    X            1
2  vijam    X            2
3  vijam    X            3
4  vijam    Y            4
5  vijam    X            5
6  vijam    X            6
7  vijam    X            7
8  vijam    X            8
9  vijam    X            9
10 vijam    Y            10
```

where the cells in column `Count` are produced by the formula

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)
```

but I want the data to be counted for each case type. For example, in the fourth row, the count should be `1` for case type `Y`. How can I do this?

I want to do this so I can get 15th & 40th case of each category for sample quality checks.

Comment: Can't you just replace `A` with `B` in the formula?

Comment: In case you want to count the CASE column then apply the Countif Formula for B column instead of A !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count values in more than one column,
use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2, $B$2:$B2,$B2)
```

Comment: I'ts working properly ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **SUMPRODUCT** function:

C2: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:B2=B2)*($A$2:A2=A2))`

[image]